# How can I switch the `selected` style easily in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

How can I switch the `selected` style easily?

In the template I have a nav:

```
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item selected" @click="clickLi(0)"><router-link to="/">首页</router-link></li>
    <li class="nav-item" @click="clickLi(1)"><router-link to="/data-center">数据中心</router-link></li>
  </ul>
```

in the methods:

```
clickLi(page_num){
    // there I have to clear all the li `selected` style, then add the style to the page_num.
}
```

in `Vue` whether there is a better way to realize this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Cass and Style Binding Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

pseudo example below, also added some shorcuts to vue-router to avoid the router-link component, you just can bind the :to to the `<li>`

```
<li
   v-for="(item, $index) in routes" 
   @click="selectedIndex = $index"
   :class="{'item-selected': $index == selectedIndex}"
   :to="item.path">{{ item.name }}</li>


// on component
data() {
  return { 
    selectedIndex: null,
    routes: [{path:'/', name: 'home'},{path:'/data-center', name:'data center'}] 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the data you return a `selected_num` param:

```
data() {
    return {
        selected_num: 0
    }
}
```

in your template:

```
 <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item" :class="selected_num===0 ? 'selected' : ''" @click="selected_num=0"><router-link to="/">首页</router-link></li>
    <li class="nav-item" :class="selected_num===1 ? 'selected' : ''" @click="selected_num=1"><router-link to="/data-center">数据中心</router-link></li>
  </ul>
```

you even do not need the method.